# ssh-host-config script still finds the user account cyg_server when it's deleted

Tags: windows-7, linux, ssh, cygwin, sshd

I removed sshd service and deleted the privilegded user account created by the script. Now I want to re-install sshd, and am having trouble with the ssh-host-config script.

It still finds the user "cyg_server" and want's to use it for installing sshd, but the account doesn't exist because it's been deleted.

```
*** Warning: cyg_server is in /etc/passwd, but the local
*** Warning: machine's SAM does not know about cyg_server.
*** Warning: Perhaps cyg_server is a pre-existing domain account.
*** Warning: Continuing, but check if this is ok.
*** Info: You appear to be running Windows XP 64bit, Windows 2003 Server,
*** Info: or later.  On these systems, it's not possible to use the LocalSystem
*** Info: account for services that can change the user id without an
*** Info: explicit password (such as passwordless logins [e.g. public key
*** Info: authentication] via sshd).

*** Info: If you want to enable that functionality, it's required to create
*** Info: a new account with special privileges (unless a similar account
*** Info: already exists). This account is then used to run these special
*** Info: servers.

*** Info: Note that creating a new user requires that the current account
*** Info: have Administrator privileges itself.

*** Info: The following privileged accounts were found: 'cyg_server' .

*** Info: This script plans to use 'cyg_server'.
*** Info: 'cyg_server' will only be used by registered services.
*** Query: Do you want to use a different name? (yes/no)
```

My system is Windows 7 Ultimate, with Cygwin and openSSH.

Q: What should I do, so the script creates the privilegded user "cyg_server" again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to this problem, delete user "cyg_server" and "sshd" from the passwd file, I think it's /etc/passwd.